# Is there a fuzzy finder option for vi?

Tags: vim, vi, editors, vimrc, plugin

I'm a convert to and now big fan of vim

However there's still one thing that I'm envious of in other editors:
Fuzzy finder matching

Is there an option or plugin for those to work the way I see it working in various other editors?

Answer (score 2):

A good solution that I installed is https://github.com/junegunn/fzf

A couple of additional customizations I made were:

A command line alias:

```
alias ci='vi $(FZF)' # Just easier to type
```

Plus I added this to my .vimrc:

```
nmap :f :FZF # less typing
```

so I can just type `:f[RETURN]` while within vi

Comment: This looks wonderful. I especially like that it integrates with `ag`, which I'm already using.

Answer (score 0):

The [CtrlP](https://ctrlpvim.github.io/ctrlp.vim/) plugin for Vim allows fuzzy searching of files, buffers, most recently used files, tags and has [extensions](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim/tree/extensions) for searching directories, quickfix errors, scripts in the Vims runtime path, undo history, lines in buffers and changes.

It's written in pure Vimscript and supports MacVim, gVim and Vim 7.0+. It also has full support for Vim's regexp syntax as search patterns and allows multiple files to be opened at once using a single search.

The latest version can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim)